# Javascript Function Is Preventing Menu Anchor Links From Working

Tags: javascript, html, function, hyperlink, menu

Hello my menu links wont Connect to the other web pages. Im pretty sure one of my javascript functions is causing these menu links to not work but im not sure how to figure out how to fix this.

I added a function that creates a menu underline under each menu. So if i had to guess this is probably what is causing the issue. You can see the website live if you click on the link below.

http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

```js
// ============= MENU HOVER UNDERLINE EFFECT - START =================

//  Menu Underline Function - START

(function() {

  const target = document.querySelector(".target");
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".mynav a");
  const colors = ["#f7c51e"];
  // const colors = ["deepskyblue", "orange", "firebrick", "gold", "magenta", "black", "darkblue"];

  function mouseenterFunc() {
    if (!this.parentNode.classList.contains("active")) {
      for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].parentNode.classList.contains("active")) {
          links[i].parentNode.classList.remove("active");
        }
        // links[i].style.opacity = "0.25";
      }

      this.parentNode.classList.add("active");
      this.style.opacity = "1";

      const width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      const height = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      const left = this.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.pageXOffset;
      const top = this.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
      const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

      target.style.width = `${width}px`;
      target.style.height = `${height}px`;
      target.style.left = `${left}px`;
      target.style.top = `${top}px`;
      target.style.borderColor = color;
      target.style.transform = "none";
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => e.preventDefault());
    links[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseenterFunc);
  }

  function resizeFunc() {
    const active = document.querySelector(" .mynav li.active");

    if (active) {
      const left = active.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.pageXOffset;
      const top = active.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

      target.style.left = `${left}px`;
      target.style.top = `${top}px`;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeFunc);


// Event Listener To Remove Line From Floating in Air When Leaving Dropdown Box - START

document.querySelector(".mynav").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  target.removeAttribute("style");
})
  
// Event Listener To Remove Line From Floating in Air When Leaving Dropdown Box - END

})();

// ============= MENU HOVER UNDERLINE EFFECT - END =================


// ============= Add "Responsive" Class  When Click On "Menu Click Here" Hamburger - Menu Dropdown =================


function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mybottomnav");
  if(x.classList.contains("responsive")) {
    x.classList.remove("responsive");
  } else {
    x.classList.add("responsive");
  }
}


// // This code has an error - It removes the sticky in mobile view
// function myFunction() {
//     var x = document.getElementById("mybottomnav");
//     if (x.className === "bottomnav") {
//       x.className += " responsive";
//     } else {
//       x.className = "bottomnav";
//     }
//   }




// ============= WHITE NAVBAR STICKY =================


// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {stickyFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("mybottomnav");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = mybottomnav.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function stickyFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    mybottomnav.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    mybottomnav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}


// Fixed White Navbar Sticky Dropdown To Work on Mobile.


// function fixed_top_menu() {
//   var windows = $(window);
//   windows.on("scroll", function () {
//       var header_height = $(".bottomnav").height();
//       var scrollTop = windows.scrollTop();
//       if (scrollTop > header_height) {
//           $(".bottomnav").addClass("sticky");
//       } else {
//           $(".bottomnav").removeClass("sticky");
//       }
//   });
// }
// fixed_top_menu();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,900&display=swap');


/* 
YELLOW - #f7c51e
GREY - #363636
background white - #f6f6f6

*/



* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}


.color-overlay-container {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.color-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}


.btn-black{
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.btn-yellow{
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    color:  white;
    background: #f7c51e;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}


body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


p {
    margin: .5rem 0;
}

/* Utility Classes */

/* Grid Container */


.grid-container {
display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
}

.grid-container-2 {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
}


/* Grid Container - END */


.container {
    max-width: 1404px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}


.text-yellow {
    color: #f7c51e;
}

.bg-yellow {
    background: #f7c51e;
    color: black;
}

.bg-grey {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: black;
}

.bg-black {
    background:black;
    color: white;
}


.l-heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.m-heading {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.lead {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 0.75rem 0;
}



/* Padding */

.py-1 {
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
}

.py-2 {
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.py-3 {
    padding: 3rem 0;
}


/* All Around Padding */

.p-1 {
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.p-2 {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.p-3 {
    padding: 3rem;
}


/* Utility Classes - END */



/* ================  HOME PAGE ==================== */


/* HEADER */



.site-header {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.site-header .header-container {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

/* BLACK BAR */

.site-header .header-container .header-container_wrap {
    padding: 30px 5px;
    /* background: red; */
}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .contact-info {
    display: flex;

}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .quality-logo {
    margin-right: 3rem;
    line-height: 5px;
}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .quality-logo p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}


#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}


#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
/* 
#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item .facebook-like {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
} */

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item .facebook-like {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black; /* Blue background */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: none; /* Some padding */
  font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item .facebook-like:hover {
   
/* Darker background on mouse-over */

    color: #f7c51e;
  
}



#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item .fas  {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #f7c51e;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
}


#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .contact-info .item .fas  {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #f7c51e;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #363636;
}

/* ========================== Bottom White Header Menu  - START ================ */


/* Menu Underline */


.mynav a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 15px;
  }
  
  .target {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .mynav a,
  .target {
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  }



  /* ================================ STICKY ========================*/


/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

  }

  .bottomnav.sticky {
      padding: 0rem;
  }

  .bottomnav.sticky .items .item {
      margin: auto;
  }

  .bottomnav.sticky .items .item:nth-child(2)  {
      display: none;
  }


/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
/* .sticky + .swiper-container {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
 */


.bottomnav {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem;
    z-index: 1200;
  }


  #mybottomnav .items {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
  }
  

  #mybottomnav .items .item .mynav ul{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
  }
  

  #mybottomnav .items .item .mynav ul li{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
  }
  

  #mybottomnav .items .item .mynav ul li:nth-child(4){
      margin-left: .5rem;
      /* background-color: red; */
  }
  
  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
  .bottomnav a {
    /* float: left;
    display: block; */
    color: rgb(94,94,94);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  
  /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

/*     
    .active {
     color: black;
    font-weight: 600; 
    color: #363636;
   }  */
  

  /* Hide the link that should open and close the bottomnav on small screens */
  .bottomnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  

  /* ============================ DROP DOWN MENU =============================== */
  /* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    /* float: left; */
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the bottomnav */
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    /* color: rgb(94,94,94); */
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f7c51e;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(94,94,94);
  }
  
  /* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.mynav   .dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  /* Add a dark background on bottomnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
  .bottomnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    /* background-color: red; */
    color: black;
    

  }
  
  /* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    /* background-color: red; */
    color: black;
    
  }

  
  /* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    z-index: 101;
  }
  
  
  /* SEARCH ICONS */

  #mybottomnav .items .item .fa-search{
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      color: #363636;
  }




/* ========================== Bottom White Header Menu - END ================ */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Keywords -->
    <meta name="description" content="Mulching Company for any type of commercial, government or private client!">
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Quality_Improvements_favicon_Logo.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-REHJTs1r2ErKBuJB0fCK99gCYsVjwxHrSU0N7I1zl9vZbggVJXRMsv/sLlOAGb4M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CSS STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="css/mobile.css">

    <!-- text animation css -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons/css/tachyons.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tachyons-animate.css"> -->


    <!-- Swiper Header Slider -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/swiper.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css"> -->


    <title>Quality Mulching</title>
</head>



<body id="home">


    <!-- Header Container -->

    <!-- Navbar-Black -->
    <div id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <nav class="header-container">

            <!-- Top Black Header Bar -->
            <div class="header-container_wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="quality-logo">
                            <a href="https://www.lonestarwebandgraphics.com">
                                <img border="0" alt="quality-logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="quality-logo" >
                                </a>
                            <!-- <img src="img/Quality_Improvements_250PX_Logo.png" alt="quality-logo"> -->
                            <p>Offering Quality work at a fair price to the Central Texas area.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="item">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                                <div class="contact-block__value-wrap">
                                    <p> Call Today</p>
                                    <p><strong>(555-2042</strong></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
                                <div class="contact-block__value-wrap">
                                    <p>Mon-Fri:<strong> 7am to 7pm</strong></p>
                                    <p>Sat & Sun: 9am-4pm</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                                <p>Serving Central Texas</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <button class="facebook-like">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                                    <p>LIKE US</p>
                                </button>
                                <!-- <div class="facebook-like">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                                    <p>LIKE US</p>
                                </div> -->
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- ======================== Bottom White header START ======================-->


            <div class="bottomnav" id="mybottomnav">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="item">
                            <nav class="mynav">

                                <!-- <a href="#home" class="active">Menu Click Here</a> -->
                                <!-- Hamburger -->
                                <ul>
                                    <div class="hamburger">
                                        <!-- <p class="active">Menu Click Here</p> -->
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><p>Menu Click Here </p>  &#9776;</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                    
                                    <!-- DROPDOWN MENU -->
                                    
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                                <button class="dropbtn">
                                                
                                                    <a href="services.html">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                                    
                                                </button>
                                                
                                                <div class="dropdown-content">
                                                    <a href="brush-mulching-land-clearing.html">Brush Mulching & Land Clearing</a>
                                                    <a href="mapping-measurement.html">Mapping & Measurement</a>
                                                    <a href="erosion-mitigation-driveways-roads.html">Erosion Mitigation / Driveways / Roads</a>
                                                    <a href="landscaping-drainage-management.html">Landscaping & Drainage Management</a>
                                                    <a href="foundation-pads.html">Foundation & Pads</a>
                                                    <a href="general-dirt-work.html">General Dirt Work & Tank Pond Trenching</a>
                                                    <a href="demolition-clean-up.html">Demolition & Clean Up</a>
                                                    <a href="septic-installation.html">Septic Installation</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                  
                                    <!-- DROPDOWN MENU END -->
                                    
                                    <li><a href="photo-gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="video-example.html">Video Example</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                                    <!-- <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a> -->
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                            

                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="target"></span>

            <!-- ======================== Bottom White header END ======================-->
            
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- HEADER CONTAINER END -->
```

Comment: remove this `links[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => e.preventDefault());`

Comment: In js/main.js you are removing the default behavior of each link. look at line 44

Comment: You are the man! Thank you so much. How did you know this? Did you see this issue before or did you debug and notice this? Im trying to get better at javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by
Removing -  links[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => e.preventDefault());
in javascript.